# How to update a MySQL DB from a REST client application?

Tags: database, rest, authentication, jersey, put

I've developed **REST services** in **Jersey**, that were generated from a **MySQL DB**. I'm able to GET/PUT information from/in the database from the web services page (URL).
Now I'm developing a client application for that, with security. I'm capable of do a GET from de Database, but how can I update it? With a **PUT method**...

Thanks

There is my both experiences with the GET (the first one using security with **HttpBasicAuthFilter**, the second with **HttpURLConnection**):

```
        public class BasicAuthenticationClient {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ExampleResourceClient erc = new ExampleResourceClient();
            erc.setUsernamePassword("blive1", "KPsS2");
            System.out.println(erc.getMessage());
            erc.close();
        }

        static class ExampleResourceClient {

        private com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource webResource;
        private com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client client;
        private static final String BASE_URI = http://localhost:8080/LULServices/webresources";

        public ExampleResourceClient() {
        com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig config = new com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig();
        client = com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(config);
        client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());
        webResource = client.resource(BASE_URI).path("entities.user");
        }

        public String getMessage() throws com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException {
        WebResource resource = webResource;
        return resource.accept(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
        }

        public void putMessage(Object requestEntity) throws com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException {
                webResource.type(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).put(requestEntity);
        }

        public void close() {
        client.destroy();
        }

        public void setUsernamePassword(String username, String password) {
        client.addFilter(new com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter(username, password));
        }
     }
 }
```

---

```
public class GETurlConnectionClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        new GETurlConnectionClient();
    }

    public GETurlConnectionClient()
    {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {
        String webPage = "http://localhost:8080/LULServices/webresources/entities.userview";
            String name = "blive2";
        String password = "microio";

            Authenticator myAuth = new Authenticator() 
            {
             final String USERNAME = "blive1";
             final String PASSWORD = "KPsS2";

             @Override
             protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
             {
              return new PasswordAuthentication(USERNAME, PASSWORD.toCharArray());
             }
            };

            Authenticator.setDefault(myAuth);

            String authString = name + ":" + password;
        System.out.println("auth string: " + authString);
        byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
        String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
        System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);

           URL urlToRequest = new URL(webPage);
           urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlToRequest.openConnection();

           urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
           System.out.println("Authorization : Basic " + authStringEnc);

           Map<String, List<String>> hf = urlConnection.getHeaderFields();
           for (String key : hf.keySet())
           System.out.println(key + ": " + urlConnection.getHeaderField(key));

           // Display request method, responde code and response message
           System.out.println("Request method is " + urlConnection.getRequestMethod());
           System.out.println("Response code is " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
           System.out.println("Response Message is " + urlConnection.getResponseMessage());

           // Display the content
           String results = doHttpUrlConnectionAction(webPage);
           System.out.println(results);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failure processing URL: " + "http://localhost:8080/LULServices/webresources");
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
            // deal with the exception in your "controller"
        }

        finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
     }
    // Read the content 
    private String doHttpUrlConnectionAction(String webPage)
    throws Exception
    {
        URL url = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder;

        try
        {
            // create the HttpURLConnection
            url = new URL(webPage);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            // Reading from a URLConnection (not display yet)
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)  {
                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();

        }   catch (Exception e)     {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw e;
            }

        finally
        {
            // close the reader; this can throw an exception too, so wrap it in another try/catch block.
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                }
            catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of working with URLConnections and all the low level stuff going on in a HTTP connection, I suggest that you consider using a higher level API, like e.g. [Apache HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html)

You can probably find even higher level REST Client APIs, but HTTPClient should be pretty straight forward to use.

Comment: Here's a [Quick Start](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html). You can also find more in depth tutorials on the project website.

Comment: I think I'll follow your advice, once your not the first one telling me that! I'm just trying some options before choose one, because I don't know too much about this subject.

Comment: One more thing, can you answer me this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358477/authentication-in-a-client-application-for-rest-services?noredirect=1#comment21714112_15358477]